# Extract multiple strings from a free text field

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

Let's say I have a free text field called 'Note' and contains "ABC:5/52 , *back, orders received"

How do I extract '5/52' and 'back' and place them in two separate columns?

Here's what I wanted to achieve

```
QUERY:-

SELECT *,  SUBSTRING(Note, CHARINDEX(':', Note)+1, 4) as ABC, 
SUBSTRING(Note, CHARINDEX('*', Note)+1, 4) as Ret_Stat
, CHARINDEX(':', Note) AS [Colon Index]

FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Sales].[Comments]

RESULT:-
Note                                           ABC      Ret_Stat
ABC:3/52,  To give more explanation, *back     3/52      back
ABC:3wks,  To debrief, *back, r/v              3wks      back
ABC:13/09/16, see cm,  *back, new referral     13/0      back
```

My issue is i wanted to extract 3/52, 3wks, and 13/09/16  but my end result's only 13/10. 
I'd like to ask how to achieve this? as the condition of extraction may vary from 4 to 8 characters after ABC: and the table contains thousands of rows of data

Need advice. THank you.

Comment: Its all going to depend on what standard(s) are in your field.  If it is always be separated by comma use CHARINDEX to find the position of the comma and SUBSTRING() .  You can include more charindex () on : colon or space to find other positions as well. reversing the string is good to find position from end of the string in your case that has 2 commas more than that you need to look at a recursive or loop.  But you have the main 2 functions so give them a try and post some specific attempts that you have questions on.  Also LTRIM(),RTRIM(),LEFT(), and RIGHT() will come in handy

Comment: Sorry, im a newbie to sql. Hope i could get more examples on the coding part. Thank you for the reply,I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: give us a few sample strings and what you want to retrieve out of them

Comment: the best way to learn is to try. All of the rdbms's out there have documentation on the functions and there are lots of sites that explain how to use them. Also search SO for split string and you will see a lot of examples on it. charindex ms https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx substring https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: Thank you Matt and Rich Benner for the help. Would like to apologize for not being clear enough for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what you want to do. You may have to modify this a little as I don't have a lot of sample data to go on.

Test Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TempData (Notes varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TempData (Notes)
VALUES
 ('This is the first "ABC:5/52 string *back, orders received')
,('*back, orders receivedThis"ABC:5/52 string is the second one')
,('You guessed it, this *back, orders received is the third "ABC:5/52 string')
```

Query

```
SELECT
 CHARINDEX('*',Notes) AsteriskLocation
,SUBSTRING(Notes,CHARINDEX('*',Notes)+1,4) AfterAsterisk
,CHARINDEX(':',Notes) ColonLocation
,SUBSTRING(Notes,CHARINDEX(':',Notes)+1,4) AfterColon
FROM #TempData
```

Result

```
AsteriskLocation    AfterAsterisk   ColonLocation   AfterColon
36                  back            23              5/52
1                   back            31              5/52
22                  back            62              5/52
```

I've left the locations separately so that you can see how they're used in the query. You could search for strings too using the same method.